# Tornado WebSocketHandler won't respond to SSL request

Tags: python, ssl, websocket, tornado

I have a Tornado HTTPServer initialized like so:

```
ssl_options = {
    "certfile": "mycert.crt",
    "keyfile": "mykey.key"
}
server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application, xheaders=True,
        ssl_options=ssl_options)
```

It has a WebSocketHandler with an `open()` method.

When I attempt to open a secure websocket connection via Javascript from the Chrome 30 console, like

```
var sock = new WebSocket("wss://localhost:9001/mywebsocket");
```

the connection does not open successfully, there is no log output, and the WebSocketHandler's `open()` is not called.

**How can I open and maintain a secure (SSL) WebSocket connection to a Javascript client in Tornado?**

Attempting an insecure connection, like

```
var sock = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:9001/mywebsocket");
```

results in the following error output in the Tornado log:

```
2013-10-08 13:59:55,305 tornado.general 820 : SSL Error on 8 ('192.168.149.27', 62851): [Errno 1] _ssl.c:490: error:1407609C:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:http request
```

Also in this case, the connection is not opened successfully and `open()` isn't called.

Additional info: The number after the IP in the error message (62851 in the above example) increases with every request, secure or otherwise. I don't know what that number is but it does indicate that the request is at least getting to the server.

Also, removing `ssl_options` from the constructor and making insecure (`ws://`) requests to the server fixes the issue.

The certificate being used is self-signed. To communicate with an HTTP endpoint of the server via curl, I had to use the `--insecure` flag.

Answer (score 1):

If you're starting the connection from the javascript console, the browser doesn't have a chance to show you the self-signed certificate warning and give you a chance to accept it.  If you go to `https://localhost:9001` first and accept the certificate there, does it work?